# Create number of folders in Powershell Script

Tags: powershell, if-statement

The script needs to read the argument and if it is greater than 15 exit or less than 1 exit. Having troubles with the "IF" Statements. Keeps giving me Missing Parenthesis errors.

```
$post = Read-Host 'How many folders would you like to create?' 
$post
If ($post -gt 15)
{
echo "Error too many arguments"
exit
}
elseif ($post -lt 1)
{
echo "Error: Not enough arguements"
exit
}
$intFolders = $post
$intPad
$i = 1
New-Variable =Name striPrefix -Value "testFolder" -Option constant
do {
if ($i -lt 15)
{$intPad = 0
New-Item -path c:\mytest -name $strPrefix$intPad$i -type directory}
else
{New-Item -path c:\mytest -name $strPrefix$i -type directory}
$i++
}until ($i -eq $intFolders+1)
```

Comment: FYI `$input` is an automatic variable in PowerShell so I would advise against using that name.

Answer (score 4):

PowerShell Syntax for `IF` statements looks like this:

```powershell
If ($Input -gt 15)
{
echo "Error too many arguments"
}
```

You can refer to [about_if](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847876.aspx) for more information.